# How do I properly access Google through IPV6?

Tags: dns, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to access Google through IPv6. However, it seems to want to send me back to IPv4! I did a DNS lookup on IPv6.google.com at http://centralops.net/co/ and found their IP, then tried this...

```
root@server:/logs# wget http://[2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a]/
--2011-09-14 12:10:13--  http://[2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a]/
Connecting to 2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2011-09-14 12:10:14--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.113.106, 74.125.113.147, 74.125.113.99, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.113.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.2'

[ <=>                                        ] 11,670      --.-K/s   in 0.02s

2011-09-14 12:10:14 (474 KB/s) - `index.html.2' saved [11670]
```

How do I access Google (or other websites) solely over IPv6?

I tested Facebook as well, essentially same result (301 redirect).

Comment: this is something with lots of dependencies - like your OS, network settings, router settings/capabilities, provider etc.

Answer (score 9):

The "identity" (*origin*) of a web site is determined by the hostname you access it by. This redirect may be simply to ensure the site works as intended (e.g. having access to your login session cookie), not specifically to reject IPv6 access.

Try adding an IPv6 address for `www.google.com` in your hosts file instead, or using `wget --header="Host: www.google.com" http://[2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a]/` to override the URL-determined host header.

Comment: This is strongly discouraged as IP-addresses can change.

Answer (score 6):

In order to avoid problems they announce their AAAA records only to DNS peers known to work.

From http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/:

> Google over IPv6 uses the IPv4 address of your DNS resolver to
>   determine whether a network is IPv6-capable. If you enable Google over
>   IPv6 for your resolver, IPv6 users of that resolver will receive AAAA
>   records for IPv6-enabled Google services.

Answer (score 3):

At least for the search engine, the URL [`http://ipv6.google.com`](http://ipv6.google.com) should work.

Comment: https://ipv6-test.com/ also very good for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Find a carrier on the [trusted testers list](http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/). Then lots of google-domains will be IPv6-accessible.

[Sixxs](https://www.sixxs.net/news/2009/#dnsresolversandgoogleoveripv6-0401) is on this list for example, but you need to reconfigure and use their name servers.

Sorry, I don't know any further carriers on this list.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP might not provide an IPv6 address for your network. There are sites that can show your public IPv6 address and test the browser's readiness.

From the command line you can check as follows ([Ubuntu example](http://itfreetraining.com/lab/ubuntu-teredo/)):

```
$ ping6 google.com
ping6: connect: Network is unreachable
```

An alternative is to use [Teredo tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling), for example, by using [Miredo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/miredo.8.html).

```
$ sudo apt-get install miredo
```

Now:

```
$ ping6 google.com
PING google.com(2a00:1450:400b:c01::71 (2a00:1450:400b:c01::71)) 56 data bytes
...
$ wget http://[2a00:1450:400b:c01::71]/
--2020-09-29 18:15:09--  http://[2a00:1450:400b:c01::71]/
Connecting to [2a00:1450:400b:c01::71]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-09-29 18:15:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

And `wget http://ipv6.google.com` should download `index.html`. I've seen no redirection.

In the case of the OP, obviously the issue was something else, since the connection was reported as successful.