# Not able to ping to IPV6 address from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ping, ipv6

Mine is Windows 7 both on laptop(home) and PC(office). I've also tested checked this from a school on Win8 PC . Why I can't ping any IPV6 address?

I've disabled Eset nod32 completely but still:

```
>ping ipv6.google.com
Ping request could not find host ipv6.google.com. Please check the name and try again
```

While nslookup(Win7) is working fine:

```
>nslookup ipv6.google.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ipv6.l.google.com
Address:  2404:6800:4007:805::200e
Aliases:  ipv6.google.com
```

**IPCONFIG ** (Win8 PC)

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CID-7244
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : removed.ac.in
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : removed.ac.in

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : removed.ac.in
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-45-C4-26-18-C7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.1.56(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 17, 2015 8:11:07 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 21, 2015 8:10:32 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.18
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.16
                                       10.1.1.17
                                       10.1.1.19
                                       10.1.1.18
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.removed.ac.in:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : removed.ac.in
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What's the exact result when passing the domain name to `nslookup`?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://superuser.com/questions/335639/how-do-i-properly-access-google-through-ipv6)

Comment: do you have actual ipv6 support from your ISP? What's the output of ipconfig?

Answer (score -1):

you need to put the -6 option

```
ping -6 ipv6.google.com
```

Comment: AFAIK that just forces IPv6 to be preferred, but it's not an absolute requirement. Not 100% sure without looking it up though.

Comment: And it doesn't fix the problem. I can reproduce it.

Comment: Same response with -6 option.